# bean scope in xml not working

Tags: spring

singleton bean scope in XML spring not working.only prototype working.Even without any scope tag prototype is working.

XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="restaurant" class="bean_scope.Restaurant1" scope="singleton">         <!-- scope="singleton" -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Java class for setter methods:

```
package bean_scope;

public class Restaurant1 {

    private String welcomeNote;

    public void setWelcomeNote(String welcomeNote) {
        this.welcomeNote = welcomeNote;
    }

    public void greetCustomer(){
        System.out.println(welcomeNote);
    }   
}
```

Java Spring Test class:

```
package bean_scope;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Restaurant1Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Restaurant1 restaurantOb1=(Restaurant1) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean_scope/SpringConfig1.xml")
            .getBean("restaurant");
        restaurantOb1.setWelcomeNote("Welcome");
        restaurantOb1.greetCustomer();

        Restaurant1 restaurantOb2=(Restaurant1) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean_scope/SpringConfig1.xml")
            .getBean("restaurant");
        //restaurantOb2.setWelcomeNote("Hello");
        restaurantOb2.greetCustomer();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 Welcome
 null
```

Please help me with this why singleton scope is not working

Comment: I dont see any problem here. you are creating two application contexts and therefore two Restaurant beans will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create two independent instances of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, each one will have its own singleton instance of the bean. The `singleton` scope means there will only be one instance of the bean *within the Spring context* - but you have two contexts there.

This would produce the result you're expecting:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean_scope/SpringConfig1.xml");

Restaurant1 restaurantOb1=(Restaurant1) ctx.getBean("restaurant");
restaurantOb1.setWelcomeNote("Welcome");
restaurantOb1.greetCustomer();

Restaurant1 restaurantOb2=(Restaurant1) ctx.getBean("restaurant");
//restaurantOb2.setWelcomeNote("Hello");
restaurantOb2.greetCustomer();
```